# Good approach of using the R class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Lately, I'm refactoring my `RecycelrView's Adapter` code. At this moment it looks like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    when (viewType) {
        TransportListData.HEADER_TYPE -> {
            val headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holder_header, parent, false)
            return HeaderHolder(headerView)
        }
        TransportListData.ROUTE_TYPE -> {
            val routeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holder_route, parent, false)
            return RouteHolder(routeView)
        }
        TransportListData.STOP_TYPE -> {
            val busStopView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holder_bus_stop, parent, false)
            return StopHolder(busStopView)
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("viewType returned unexpected type: $viewType")
    }
}
```

And now I'm wondering how can I improve it. I came up with an idea of changeing constant values of `viewType`  from random number to constants from `R.layout`. So the code looks like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false)
    return when (viewType) {
        TransportListData.HEADER_TYPE ->  HeaderHolder(view)
        TransportListData.ROUTE_TYPE ->  RouteHolder(view)
        TransportListData.STOP_TYPE ->  StopHolder(view)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("viewType returned unexpected type: $viewType")
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to know your opinion about it. Is it good to use constants from `R` class, especially when it comes to unit tests? How can I improve `onCreateViewHolder()` code to be more readable and maintainable without any libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a static `create` (or something else) method to my `ViewHolder` classes, which sort of shifts the responsibility of creating the holder from the adapter itself to the `ViewHolder` class.

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): ViewHolder(itemView) {
    companion object {
        const val layout = R.layout.item_layout

        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder {            
            return MyViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the main constructor can be set to private to prevent any unwanted calls. `class MyViewHolder private constructor(itemView: View)`